# Oracle error:missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code:

```
SELECT SIGHTING_ID,MAX((SQRT(POWER(LATITUDE-(-28),2)+(POWER(LONGITUDE-151,2)) AS DISTANCE
FROM SIGHTINGS
```

I think the problem is the bracket. I have tried lots of combination but the error still here. What can I do or the query is wrong?

Comment: In your query you have 7 open parentheses and only 4 closed. You know that you should close each open parenthesis? Then you have a select of an attribute and an aggregate function without a GROUP BY. This is not possible in SQL.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What is the error you are seeing? What do you expect to get?

Comment: why don't you trust the compiler? :) it told you the problem from the get-go. and why do you open 2 ( for max?

Comment: You should use an editor with a bracket matching capability. Most programmer tools have this feature: TextPad, NotePad++, SQL Developer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in error you missing Right Parenthesis. Here is the correct query

```
SELECT SIGHTING_ID,
       Max(Sqrt(Power(LATITUDE - ( -28 ), 2) + ( Power(LONGITUDE - 151, 2) ))) AS DISTANCE
FROM   SIGHTINGS                                                          --^^
GROUP BY SIGHTING_ID
```

Added two right parenthesis and removed one unwanted left parenthesis. The above query returns the maximum distance for each `SIGHTING_ID`

If you only the record with maximum distance then try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT SIGHTING_ID,
               Sqrt(Power(LATITUDE - ( -28 ), 2) + ( Power(LONGITUDE - 151, 2) )) AS DISTANCE
        FROM   SIGHTINGS
        ORDER  BY DISTANCE DESC) 
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! But it show other error that is  not a single-group group function, do it mean I need to use group by to solve this?

Comment: @ReginaldHo - Missed to add `Group by` check now

Comment: But after execute it, i thought it will only show 1 row of data but its show tones of row, how can i show only the maximum of the distance?

Comment: @ReginaldHo - Check the update

Comment: Thx alot!! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Included Group By clause, as you are using MAX function in the query.

```
SELECT SIGHTING_ID,
       MAX(SQRT(POWER(LATITUDE-(-28),2)+POWER(LONGITUDE-151,2))) AS DISTANCE 
FROM   SIGHTINGS 
GROUP BY SIGHTING_ID;
```